# Single product link in woocomerce

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change my product link from

`produkt/produkt-name`

to

`produkt/category/subcategory/product_id/product-name/?myvariableParsedByJson`

Please give me any tips how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try in the WordPress Backend: Settings » Permalinks - typically reachable via URL: http://domain.ext/wp-admin/options-permalink.php.

Next time please take a look at the WooCommerce documentation, here [Permalinks](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/permalinks/).

Comment: *Note to moderators*: I actually flagged this prematurely. @nicogaldo The quality is bad though, next time please add a sufficient explanation.

Comment: Thanks for answer @nicogaldo. But how to write own format using php?

Comment: @user1235123 [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769028/woocommerce-product-id-in-url). I have no time to prove it, but I think it comes close to what you're looking.